# How to get Specific Tags in g(group) Tags in SVG using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, nodes

Here, 
 I customized [SVG-EDITOR](https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) and also Changing Right click option in work-area.
i am struggling to get Specific Tags like `Rect,Line,Path and etc` from `<g>` tags in SVG using java-script
Here i get specific tags node Name using this code.

```
var test =selectedElement.nodeName;
```

It working fine for me and it will shown as **rect,line and path.**
but I have dynamic `<g>` tags and also `rect, line` are placed inside that group tags.'
Here Sample code

> ```
>     <g id="svg_28">
>            <rect stroke_width="0" id="svg_1" height="141" width="398" y="68" x="399" 
>     stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="#f7b7b2"/>
>           </g>
>
>           <g id="svg_33">
>            <path id="svg_2" 
> d="m508,106c-1,0 606,-26 606,-26c0,0 -573,125 -573,125c0,0 -33,-99 -33,-99z"  stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#729FCF"/>
>           </g>
> ```

And also try to get  tags inside tags nodename using this method

```
console.log(elem.getBBox());
console.log(elem.getBoundingClientRect());
```

But it results only **x,y,left,right,top,bottom,width,height** of object only.I need node Name of selected  tags object.
How to get that select node name?is it possible to get selected Node name?

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem unless you post more complete javascript showing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson.. I update my question..i working in right click functionality in svg editor..

Answer (score 0):

A function that will parse the svg and on each tag will do something

```
    var g = "g";
    var path = "path";
    var rect = "rect";
    var circle = "circle";
    var line = "line";
    var polygon = "polygon";

    // will parse the svg and on each tag element will do something
    // el is the element ex $('.mySVG')
    var svgTags = function(el){
        el.children().each(function(){
            if($(this).is(g)){
                svgTags($(this));
            }else if($(this).is(path)){
                // do something
            }else if($(this).is(rect)){
                // do something
            }else if($(this).is(circle)){
                // do something
            }else if($(this).is(line)){
                // do something
            }else if($(this).is(polygon)){
                // do something
            }
        });
    }
```